# Question about proof in Neukirch

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading the proof of Proposition 2.10 in Neukirch. Here is the result, given the classic $AKBL$ setup.

> Prop. If $L|K$ separable and $A$ is a PID, then every finitely generated $B$-submodule $M\neq 0$ of $L$ is a free $A$-module of rank $[L:K]$. In particular, $B$ admits an integral basis over $A$.
>
> Proof: Let $M\neq 0$ be a finitely generated $B$-submodule of $L$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ a basis of $L|K$. Multiplying by an element of $A$, we may arrange the $\alpha_i$ to lie in $B$. We then have $dB\subseteq A\alpha_1+\cdots+A\alpha_n$ by Lem 2.9 ($d$ is discriminant), in particular, rank$(B)\leq[L:K]$, etc.

I am wondering how rank $(B)$ is even defined. Aren't we suppsoed to prove that $B$ is a free $A$-module? So how does this final assertion work and why is it true?

Comment: What is $B{}{}$?

Comment: If $A$ is a PID, every finitely generated, torsion-free $A$-module is free.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling to understand Neukirch's proof here as well, and I shall share my understanding of his proof below. I'm also a new learner on algebraic number theory, so I'm sincerely sorry if there are mistakes and misunderstandings.

Personally, I think that one should first prove a weaker result:

> **Proposition**: Let $A$ be an integrally closed integral domain with field of fraction $K$, and let $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in a separable extension $L$ of $K$ of degree $m$. Then there exists free $A$-submodules $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ of $L$, such that $M \subset B \subset M^{\prime}$.

And in paricular,

> **Corollary $(\star)$**: When $A$ is noetherian, $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, and furthermore, when $A$ is a PID, $B$ is free of rank $[L:K]$.

The corollary gives the second result (after *In particular*) of Proposition (2.10) in Neukirch. So it has already been enough if we are only interested in the existence of integral basis of $B$ over $A$. I shall provide a proof of the entire Proposition (2.10) in Neukirch using the above corollary.

**PROOF of the quoted proposition and corollary $(\star)$**: The proof of the above proposition and corollary can be found as Proposition 2.29 in Milne's note "Algebraic Number Theory", or [Zariski-Samuel] Vol.1, Ch.V., Sect. 4.

**PROOF of (2.10)**: So to prove (2.10), Let $(\mu_i)_{i=1, \ldots, r} \in M$ be a system of generators of the $B$-module $M$. Then there is an $a \neq 0 \in A$ such that $a \mu_i \in B$ for $i=1, \ldots, r$. (This is the standard trick introduced on Page 8). So we see that $aM \subset B$. By **Corollary $(\star)$**, $B$ is a free $A$-module, where $A$ is a PID, hence $aM$ is a free $A$-module with $\text{rank}_A(aM) \leq [L:K]$. So $M$ is also a free $A$-module with $\text{rank}_A(aM) \leq [L:K]$.

To show that $\text{rank}_A(M) = [L:K]$, it remains to show that $\text{rank}_A(aM) \geq [L:K]$. This is discussed in the post: [Incomplete Proof from Neukirch about modules and algebraic integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674778/incomplete-proof-from-neukirch-about-modules-and-algebraic-integers?rq=1).

> Just to restate the discussion there (**Some of the arguments below are directly copied there from Hagen Knaf's answer.**), let $(\alpha_i)_{i=1, \ldots, n}$ be a basis of $L|K$. Multiplying by an element of $A$, we can arrange for $\alpha_i \in B$. (Still the trick introduced on Page 8) Take an element $m \in M \setminus 0$. Then the elements $\alpha_i m\in M$, $i=1,\ldots ,n$, are linearly independent over $A$, which means that the $A$-submodule $Bm$ of $M$ has rank $n$. Hence
> $$
> \text{rank}_A (M) \geq  \text{rank}_A (Bm) = n = [L:K].
> $$

This is what we desired.

Sorry for any possible mistakes above. And I'm still wondering if there is a good way to prove (2.10) directly, or understand what Neukirch means.

**THANKS**: Thanks Angina Seng for the comments in this post, and Hagen Knaf for his answer in the linked post above!