# Estimation on Module Rank in Neukirch's ANT

Tags: proof-explanation, modules, algebraic-number-theory

I'm studying the book Algebraic Number Theory of Jürgen Neukirch and I'm having some
troubles to understand a conclusion in proof of prop 2.10, page 13:

> (2.10) Proposition. If $L$ ($K$ is separable and $A$ is a principal ideal domain,
> then every finitely generated $B$ -submodule $M \neq 0$ of $L$ is a free $A$ module of
> rank $[L:K]$ . In particular, $B$ admits an integral basis over $A$.

> **Proof:** Let $M \neq 0$ be a finitely generated $B$-submodule of $L$ and
> $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n $ a basis of $L / K$. Multiplying by an element of $A$,
> we may arrange for the $\alpha_i$,
> to lie in $B$. By (2.9), we then have $d B \subset A \alpha_1 + ...+  A \alpha_n$,
> (where $d$ is the discriminant $d= d(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n)$)
> in particular, $rank(B) \ge [L : K]$, and since a system of generators of the $A$-module
> $B$ is also a system of generators of the $K$-module $L$, we have $rank(B) = [L:K]$...

Question is, why we can conclude that $rank(B) \le [L : K]$ from
the inclusion $d B \subset A \alpha_1 + ...+  A \alpha_n$ (which is obtained by (2.9))?
Is is neccessary to make this conclusion to assume $A$ to be p.i.d. or does it
hold in more general setting?

nb: I see that in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674778/incomplete-proof-from-neukirch-about-modules-and-algebraic-integers) question the OP asked about the same proof but another issue.

Comment: For numbers in $L$, $A$-linear dependence is equivalent to $K$-linear dependence (by clearing out a common denominator in a nontrivial $K$-linear relation), so an $A$-linearly independent subset of $L$ has size at most $\dim_K(L) = [L:K]$.  Thus the rank of $B$ as an $A$-module is at most $[L:K]$.  This doesn't involve $A$ being a PID: it being an integral domain is all you need.  Where you do use $A = $ PID is the argument that $B$ is a free $A$-module of rank $[L:K]$ because it is stuck between two free $A$-modules of rank $[L:K]$.

Comment: If $A$ is an integral domain that is not a field, it is *false* that an $A$-module lying between two free $A$-module of the same rank must be free (of that same rank too).

Comment: Otherwise the constructive proof may be more enlightening. Take $n\ne 0\in M$, then $M\cap nK = m_1 A$, for some $m_1\in M$, this is where we use that $A$ is a PID, and $M/m_1A$ is a finitely generated $A$-submodule of the $[L:K]-1$ dimensional vector space $L/m_1 K$, so we can repeat replacing $M,L$ by $M_2=M/m_1A,L_2=L/m_1K$ until $[L_j:K]=0$, the obtained $m_j$ give $L=\sum_{j=1}^{[L:K]}m_jK,B=\sum_{j=1}^{[L:K]}m_jA$.

Comment: @KCd: so let me try to summarize your argument:
You claim that for every finite set $S:=\{ s_1,..., s_m \}   \subset L$ the $A$-rank 
of $As_1 + ... + As_m$ **equals** the $K$-rank (=$K$-dimension)
of $Ks_1 +... + Ks_m$, that's it? 
In our case if $B$ has $A$-rank $m$ we take $S$ the generators
$S:= \{b_1,..., b_m \} \subset B \subset L$ und use 
the equality of $K$ and $A$-rank from above, right?

Comment: @KCd: But about about your second comment I'm confused. Why we cannot
here argue in same manner as in first comment? Say we have
an $A$-module $M$ lying between two free $A$ modules
$A^s = \oplus^s_i Aa_i \subset M \subset A^r= \oplus^r_j Ab_j$.
Tensor it by $K \otimes $ and we obtain the
inclusions $K^s \subset K \otimes_A M \subset K^r$ between $K$-
vector spaces.
Chose the $K$-basis $m_1,...,m_d $ of $K \otimes M$.
Then $s \le d \le r$.

Comment: Since
every $m_i$ has the form $m_i= \sum_i m_{ij} \otimes k_j$ with 
$k_j \in K$ we can clear the demoninators and obtain generators
of $M$, or not? And then we can use the trick that $K$-independence
is the same as $A$-independence and we obtain $s \le d \le r$.
Where is the error in this "proof"?

Comment: @IsaktheXI let $I$ be a nonzero ideal in an integral domain $A$.  For a nonzero x in $I$, we have $Ax \subset I \subset A$, so $I$ lies between two free $A$-modules of rank $1$. You would be claiming $I$ is also free of rank $1$, so $I$ is principal. Thus every integral domain is a PID. I assume you know some integral domains that are not PIDs.  Thinking about them will show you where your reasoning is mistaken.

Comment: @KCd: I understand your example, so let $A$ not PID and $I$ not generated
by one element, say by two: $I =<x,y>$. But they are linear 
dependent in the sense that there exist $a, b \in A$ with
$ax+bx=0$ is a non trivial relation, because if $x,y$ are $A$ 
independent, then we tensor $Ax \subset I \subset A$ by $K$ and
obtain a two dimensional $K$-space $Kx +Ky$ contained in $K$, 
that's a contradiction, since $A$-indep equivalent to 
$K$-indep. I think I understand now what was the problem in 
my 'proof': the $K$-independent generators

Comment: of $K$-space $K \otimes M$
stay after multiplying by appropriate $a \in A$ linear
independent in $M$, but in general they not generate $M$,
that's the point, right?

Comment: @IsaktheXI sure, there was no actual reason presented for elements to generate $M$.  Concerning your example with the ideal $I$, there is no need to tensor anything: if $x$ and $y$ are nonzero in $I$ then $ax + by = 0$ when $a = y$ and $b = -x$.  More generally, in every commutative ring $R$ every pair of nonzero elements of $R$ is  $R$-linearly dependent.

Comment: Back to $rank(B) \le [L : K]$ and equivalence of $K$-independence
and $A$-indep.: so as far as I understand your concern 
here we need freeness
of $B$ to assure that the basis of $B \otimes_A K$ after 
beeing 'cleared by denominators' to a still $A$-linear 
independent $A$-set, stays still a set **generating** $B$,
I think.